# Navigation Bar Lost When Open From Modal View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have this setup in my app with Swift 3:

1. `FirstViewController`: UIViewController
2. `SecondViewController`: UIViewController

   - `ContainerView` embeds

     - `MyTableViewController`: UITableViewController
3. `ThirdViewController`

I am losing **Navigation Bar** in `ThirdViewController` when it is open from `MyTableViewController` because its container `SecondViewController` (where `MyTableViewController` is embedded) is open as a Modal view.

In other words, `FirstViewController` opens `SecondViewController` as a Modal view. However, when I perform my segue in `SecondViewController`'s `MyTableViewController` I want to show `ThirdViewController` with a Navigation Bar and it is missing.

What can be done? I tried using this weird line but nothing happens:

```
self.parent?.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController", sender: self)
```

where `self.parent?.parent?` must be my `FirstViewController`.

Any better ideas to get Navigation Bar back?

Comment: does SecondViewController is presented modally?

Comment: you can use delegate pattern which will call containerVC function to perform push segue from your container view controller and embed the container in UINavigationController if its not.

Comment: try to present Navigationcontroller of ThirdViewController instead of ThirdViewController.   **OR** add naviagation bar manually in ThirdViewController if  Navigationcontroller **not exist**.

Comment: If you present the `UIViewController` it won't come under navigation stack. For that you need to add a `navigationBar` in `ThirdViewController` or `UINavigationController` for `ThirdViewController`

Comment: Yes, SecondViewController is presented modally. This is why when it presents ThirdViewController, the Nav Bar is lost. Otherwise, say if I present ThirdViewController from FirstViewController, Nav Bar will be in place